# Source location of a class

Tags: ruby

I want to find the instance methods defined inside a class (explicitly with `def`, not those deriving from other calls like `attr_accessor`)

To do that, I thought of looping the `instance_methods(false)` result and check if each method's `source_location` is the same as the class's source location.

How can I find a class's source location?

Comment: The source location for `attr_accessor` methods points to the line where `attr_accessor` was called, i.e. it usually does not differ from explicitly defined methods.

Comment: @Stefan Yes but from the `attr_accessor :foo`, the derived method `foo=` won't have the source location of the class. That's what I meant with the "explicitly", I might need to rephrase that part.

Comment: `foo=` _does_ have the same source location if `attr_accessor :foo` was called from within the class.

Comment: @Stefan true that

Comment: BTW, why do you need those methods? Maybe there's another way.

Comment: I wanted to make a utility that would generate some kind of templates for testing but you just made it impossible with your answer :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[not actually an answer to your problem, but too long for a comment]*

`source_location` doesn't seem to help here, because dynamic methods can be created with an arbitrary location:

```
# my_class.rb

class MyClass
  attr_accessor :foo

  class_eval(<<-RUBY, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1)
    def bar
    end
  RUBY

  class_eval(<<-RUBY, 'dummy.rb', 42)
    def baz
    end
  RUBY
end

p MyClass.instance_method(:foo).source_location
p MyClass.instance_method(:bar).source_location
p MyClass.instance_method(:baz).source_location
```

Output:

```
$ ruby my_class.rb
["my_class.rb", 4]
["my_class.rb", 7]
["dummy.rb", 42]
```

Comment: TIL about the thing you did with the arbitrary locations!

Comment: Those arbitrary locations are useful when you've writing something that transforms code into Ruby which it then executes, something that [ERB](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) and [HAML](http://haml.info) do, among others. That way the error can appear to originate in the source file, not some random chunk of intermediate code.